# ¿Qué deberíamos hacer a las preguntas del tipo: no he intentado pero quiero respuesta?

Tags: discusión

Buenas tardes estimados hermanos y hermanas de SOes, en los últimos días me estoy topando con preguntas del tipo "*Quiero la respuesta pero no he intentado, no sé cómo iniciar, qué me recomiendan, opiniones sobre X situación*"

Por citar una pequeña lista:

- [¿Libreria de Javascript para detectar rostro y deformar en tiempo
  real?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22456/822)
- [¿Cómo se aconseja almacenar la información en una aplicación similar
  a Waze usando Mapbox?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22452/822)
- [Repositorio de Archivos en la nube con ASP.NET C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22474/822)
- [Problema con google maps api
  JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22416/822)

Esta última la he contestado considerando que tiende a ser genérica. Por otro lado, en la primera encontré el siguiente comentario que me parece perfecto:

> *Te adelanto que Stackoverflow en español no es un sitio de recomendaciones o un sustituto de Google*

Siento que las preguntas de este tipo van en aumento y mi pregunta es: qué deberíamos hacer para frenarlas? El sitio donde andamos es bien específico: **Escribe qué has intentado y te ayudamos a resolverlo :D.** Sin embargo parece que son muy pocos nuevos usuarios que se toman el tiempo de leer el formato de preguntas. ¿Será posible de alguna manera mostrarles el contenido de: *¿Cómo preguntar?* antes de sus primeras preguntas?

Mientras tanto seguimos redactando comentarios en buen plan para manter el orden del sitio. ¿Hay algo más que podríamos hacer? ¿Qué opinan al respecto?

Comment: Deberias dejar de ser buen tipo y dejar de responder esa clase de preguntas.. ;-) Por cierto, te me adelantaste, iba preguntar exactamente eso. Es raro, soy un gran consumidor de respuestas de SO (mayormente en inglés), sin embargo nunca se me ocurriría pedir que alguien me ayude a resolver un problema sin probar durante varias horas distintas soluciones (que podrían sumar tranquilamente semanas de trabajo).

Comment: En esa pregunta de Google Maps sentí que debía responderla. Entiendo exactamente lo que dices: "nunca se me ocurriría pedir que alguien me ayude a resolver un problema sin probar durante varias horas distintas soluciones" sucede que tanto tú como quien escribe pertenecemos la 'vieja escuela' de programadores autodidactas que andan dentro de un loop de prueba y error hasta que aprendemos, cierto? Hace unos meses redacté este post: http://fredyfx.com/saludos-nueva-generacion-de-programadores espero se de tu agrado :D ¿Cómo formarías de manera correcta a esta nueva generacion de programadores?

Comment: Con la pregunta de gmap a mí me pasó al revés, hice desarrollos usando gmaps y me pareció que mirando los ejemplos de la documentación y haciendo búsquedas en google podía obtener lo que quería o al menos una versión inicial.
Por cierto buen artículo, aunque no sé si es una cuestión generacional. El mundo de los programadores sigue tienendo muchos de los mismos problemas de hace 50 años. Me parece que algunas cosas las vemos más facilmente hoy día.

Comment: Por cierto, puede que esté relacionada a esta [pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado)

Comment: preciso! gracias por publicarlo mi estimado :D

Comment: Otra discusión interesante, tangencialmente relacionada (en mi opinión), [aquí](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/788/cual-es-la-verdadera-intenci%c3%b3n-con-las-puntuaciones-negativas). Es sobre si usar o no el voto negativo a fin de mejorar las preguntas.

Comment: Parece que este tipo de preguntas son parecidas a las de [¡Hazme la tarea!](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado); yo más de una vez me he sentido tentado a responder con un [lgtfy](http://lmgtfy.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Preguntas que me surgieron hoy, pensando exactamente este tema, mientras buscaba preguntas que responder y me encontraba simplemente dejando comentarios sobre como mejorar la pregunta, como me pasó también anoche.

¿Será que no saben cómo empezar a buscar? ¿Será que no encuentran material en español y el que está en inglés les es imposible de entender? ¿Será que cómo la gente está descubriendo la comunidad simplemente prueba suerte, sin pensar en participar realmente en participar de la misma? ¿Será que prueban preguntar esperando un alma caritativa les solucione el problema (para luego irse sin marcar como correcta la solución)?

Personalmente, no voy a contestar dichas preguntas (me refiero al tipo de pregunta que menciona `fredyfx`), creo que es pan para hoy y hambre para mañana (a nivel comunidad). Seguiré dejando comentarios intentando que demuestren interés en su pregunta y en la comunidad. Prefiero contestarle a la gente que parece demostrar interés en resolver sus problemas y aprender.

**UPDATE**
Tal vez lo que haya que hacer comunidad son más guías/wikis de temas (ej: [¿Qué es inyección de SQL y cómo evitarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla), puede que con ello disminuyas este tipo de consultas.

Comment: Hacer más guías para que la gente que no se lee las guías no cometa los errores que no cometería si se leyese las guías que ya había antes de hacer más guías no va a solventar nada.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos lo mismo vale para las respuestas. Cerramos todo SE entonces?

Comment: Agrego, el finde me hubiera gustado encontrarme un par de buenas guías/ejemplos/explicaciones (de esas que entienden todos) de unos paquetes de Smalltalk. Es decir, las guías son y serán para la gente que quiere aprender.

Comment: No estamos hablando de las mismas guías. Yo me refería a las guías de uso de SOes, ¿Qué es una buena pregunta?¿Qué es un ejemplo completo, mínimo y ejecutable?, etc. Entiendo que el problema del que hablamos es que haya usuarios que hacen preguntas que no se ajustan a lo que se espera en SOes. Para mejorar una pregunta mal hecha sobre SmallTalk no hace falta una guía de SmallTalk, hace falta una guía de SOes, y esas ya existen.En cuanto a las guías de, por ejemplo Smalltalk, en castellano; ya existen, por ejemplo el libro "Programando con Smalltalk" de Diego Gómez Deck.

Comment: Ahí aclaré a cual es el tipo de guías a las que me refiero. Y retomando Smalltalk me refería a cuando estás viendo temas muy puntuales de paquetes de específicos de terceros (que por ejemplo no sabes si están discontinuados o vivos, si funcionalmente están completos y/o estables, etc.).

Comment: Volviendo a las guías de uso de SOes, no, no las van a leer en la vida.

Comment: Aunque las guías no van a resolver el problema de que mucha gente no lee, al menos si se editan algunas en formato wiki, recogerán mucha experiencia, y en las respuestas que algunos consideremos válidas, se podrían enlazar a la página wiki en cuestión.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando leo la pregunta y si el usuario no muestra el esfuerzo suficiente:

- *Si la pregunta es de muy baja calidad:* editar y mejorar el formato para claridad de la pregunta; junto con el comentario de bienvenida:

> Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
>   puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
>   es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
>   para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
>   Saludos

- **Asumir de buena fe** que el usuario simplemente no está familiarizado con el sitio, dejar un comentario de bienvenida *similar al que acabo de citar* y esperar a que el usuario asimile la nueva información.

Si ninguno de estos cambios surtieron efecto en la pregunta y/o usuario, **deja tu comentario *(o reporte "voto para cerrar, por ejemplo")* y sigue adelante.**

Answer (score 3):

Pues, yo trato cada que veo preguntas un poco mágicas como por ejemplo

***Tengo un error en javascript***

Les digo que coloquen que tipo de error, que editen su pregunta para que las personas le puedan ayudar, la mayoria de veces lo hacen otras, ni responden nada.

Pienso que se debería poner una especie de plantilla no se en las preguntas, creo yo, como que si la pregunta es algo compleja y lo que necesita preguntar es algo que hay que verlo de forma gráfica también, que ponga un gif o una imagen.

Comment: una plantilla, suena interesante, algo como: Paso 0: Comenta tu escenario Paso 1 : Escribe tu código. Paso 2: Redacta el error. Paso 3: Cuenta que más has intentado. //Algo así?

Comment: @fredyfx mejor no lo pudo haber dicho, tome su Nobel

Comment: Otra cosa mágica que veo es la falta de mostrar los valores de la varibles o del caso que les da el error.

Comment: hahaha gracias @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales :'D Este nobel se lo dedico a mi madrecita, a familia, a mis amigos, a la gran internet por darme ese acceso a conocimiento a un click de distancia y a mis buenos amigos de comunidades online especialmente de SOes, venga! construyamos uno de los mejores sitios de habla hispana para desarrolladores de software y gente de TI! #ConTodoElPower2.0!

Comment: Te hizo falta Wikipedia, El Rincon del vago, al perro y al gato XD