# ¿Cómo actuar con preguntas de baja calidad?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, código-de-conducta

Hay preguntas interesantes pero que por distintos motivos no cumplen los  cánones de calidad de SOes: falta código, no tienen ninguna investigación previa, etc.

Yo opino que en principio no se deben contestar y que lo mejor es indicarle al OP que añada más información, código o lo que corresponda y cuando lo haga se responde.

Hablando con @Jorgesys del tema me ha comentado que muchas veces el OP abandona la pregunta  a su suerte, nunca la edita ¿qué pasa entonces? ¿Dejamos la pregunta sin contestar aún teniendo una respuesta y sabiendo que podría ayudar a otros?

Se me ocurre que se podría esperar un tiempo para que el OP la edite, no sé cuanto tiempo, un día o algo así y después si no da señales de vida publicar nuestra respuesta.

¿Cómo actuáis en estos casos?

Comment: Relacionado [¿Qué deberíamos hacer a las preguntas del tipo: no he intentado pero quiero respuesta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/840/65)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué deberíamos hacer a las preguntas del tipo: no he intentado pero quiero respuesta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/840/qu%c3%a9-deber%c3%adamos-hacer-a-las-preguntas-del-tipo-no-he-intentado-pero-quiero-resp)

Answer (score 7):

Yo creo que no deberían ser respondidas las preguntas que no cumplan con los requisitos. ¿Por qué? Porque la persona que responde necesita asumir cosas para responder.

Un ejemplo claro me parece la pregunta:

- [¿Cómo puedo hacer que un arreglo me lance números pares?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/7198)

Es también muy interesante [ver la historia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/7198/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) para ver qué versión de la pregunta es la que fue respondida.

En esa pregunta, el OP (también dicho [AP o autor de la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2611)) dice que quiere que un arreglo "lance" números pares, y muestra el siguiente "código del arreglo":

```cs
int[] Numeros;
public void Vectore(int[] numeros)
{
    Numeros = numeros;
}
public void llenarVector()
{
    Random x = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<Numeros.Length;i++)
    {
        Numeros[i] = x.Next(100);
    }
}
public int[] Retorno()
{
    return Numeros;
}
```

Quienes responden, ven el código e interpretan que el OP quiere generar un arreglo con números pares entre 0 y 99 (para ellos es "claro" por el código). Sin embargo, el OP nunca menciona esto.

Tan claro es, que [Alvaro Montoro♦](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) incluso [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/7198/revisions) para incluir esto. Lo cierto es que no se sabe si el OP quería pares entre 0 y 99 o quería "todos los pares". Tampoco sabemos qué es que un arreglo lance algo. Lo único que sabemos es que tenemos en el sitio una pregunta poco clara, respondida por gente que honestamente quiere ayudar pero que asume (a mi gusto) mucho. Probablemente alguno de los que respondió dio un upvote (a una pregunta claramente mala, lo que a mi criterio hace más daño).

Yo creo que en las preguntas de baja calidad, tenemos que pedirle más datos al OP (que es el único que los tiene)... Y si no responde, entonces tiene que ser cerrada.

**¿Y qué pasa si me gustó mucho la pregunta que yo interpreté y la quiero responder igual?**

¡GENIAL! Eso es buenísimo. Hacé una pregunta clara, poné un link a la que te inspiró y respondela. No tenés por qué quedarte con ganas de responder. Incluso podés ponerle un comentario al OP con un link a tu pregunta a ver si le ayuda.

Comment: Los mayorcitos (en antiguedad, ni siquiera hablo en reputacion).. deberiamos dar el ejemplo. +1

Comment: Esto es buscarle tres pies al gato. Si te piden un arreglo que lance números pares y te ponen código en que se rellena una arreglo con números aleatorios está claro que se está pidiendo un código que rellene ese array con números pares aleatorios. Es una pregunta, no es una especificación formal.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos claramente estamos en desacuerdo :) ver esa pregunta con 3 upvotes (yo le di un downvote) me pone triste. Para mí, baja la calidad del sitio.

Comment: @g3rv4 Pues a mi lo que no me gusta es que haya tres respuestas pero como máximo 2 de esas personas han votado positivo la pregunta (tiene 3 votos y uno es mío). ¿Para qué responder una pregunta que no se merece tu voto?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos ese es otro punto en el que no estamos de acuerdo... votar y responder son acciones distintas, una respuesta no tendría que venir siempre con un upvote

Comment: @g3r4 Me ha parecido que habías escrito *Yo creo que no deberían ser respondidas las preguntas que no cumplan con los requisitos.* Si la pregunta cumple con los requisitos se merece un positivo. Si no le das el positivo y la respondes estás siendo incoherente.

Comment: A mi el ejemplo de esta pregunta me parece bastante bueno para ilustrar la situación en que asumimos premisas por nuestra cuenta. Por el código parece claro que el OP quiere números entre 0 y 99 pero no lo dice, está es su código pero ¿de donde ha sacado ese código?¿Es suyo o lo ha copiado de otro ejemplo?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos yo no creo que por sólo cumplir con los requisitos se merezca un voto, pero cada uno usa sus votos como le parece :)

Comment: Sí que está alto el listón. Hay quien piensa que con cumplir las normas al preguntar no es suficiente para que te voten positivo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos honestamente, parece que me estuvieras dando la razón :) para mi es bastante claro que no alcanza con cumplir las normas para tener un voto positivo... lo que cumplir las normas te garantiza es que tu pregunta no va a ser cerrada... que la comunidad entienda que es una "buena pregunta" es otra cosa :)

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91902/como-hacer-un-contador-que-aumente-si-no-se-encuentra-una-letra-en-una-palabra otro ejemplo donde tratamos de adivinar que quiere OP

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Está claro que cada uno usa sus votos como considera oportuno. Sin embargo, no porque esté "normalizada" significa que sea buena. Puede cumplir todas las normas pero estar muy mal redactada, dar excesiva información, etc... No hay que confundir una "pregunta válida" para el sitio de una "pregunta buena" para el sitio.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero: Una de las normas es que esté bien redactada y ser clara, así que por definición una pregunta mal redactada no cumple con todas las normas :)

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta tiene varios votos positivos es claro que no refleja la opinión de la comunidad pues tenemos muchísimas preguntas que no los cumplen, tienen votos positivos y tienes respuestas :)

Comment: @Ruben es interesante como "pese a tener muchos votos no refleja la opinión de la comunidad"... por qué será esto? porque muchos usuarios activos no visitan meta? personalmente me encantaría leer otras opiniones

Comment: @g3rv4: No me quedó claro si me estás invitando a continuar la conversación sobre esto o fue más bien algo así como "Rubén, gracias por participar, pásale el micrófono al de a lado" :)

Comment: @Rubén la primera :) dentro de otras opiniones incluyo la tuya... me resulta genuinamente interesante eso que decís de que la comunidad actúa de una forma en las preguntas y de otra al votar/discutir en meta... será que a mucha gente no le interesa discutir? que no sabe que existe meta? o que directamente no les interesa y cada uno va a seguir como viene y listo?

Comment: @g3rv4: Yo creo que la mayoría dedica poco tiempo a un sitio como SOes y aunado a esto lo peculiar que es, somos muy pocos los que sabemos acerca de Meta y que nos sentimos confiados de participar aquí.

Comment: @Rubén a mi me encantaría generar consenso en meta sobre qué nos parece que es mejor para el sitio (es muy posible que nunca logremos consenso sobre esto o sobre "si respondés y no votás está mal") y ayudar a ir moldeando el contenido en el sitio. En particular en este tema si se puede... pero si no, en otros... e invitar a los usuarios de SOes a que se den una vuelta por meta. Los consensos son siempre temporales y reversibles :)

Comment: Perdona la "pedantería", el "chocantismo" o como se le llame... "consenso" sólo se podría lograr con la participación de todos y siendo tan diversos como somos, la verdad *lo veo imposible* en particular a lo que estamos tratando en este hilo, sin embargo, coincido contigo en que me encantaría que hubiese mayor participación en discusiones como esta y en atraer a mas miembros a participar a Meta,

Answer (score 4):

Si la pregunta es interesante **y clara** aún y cuando no cumpla con todos requisitos de [¿Cómo escribir una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) publica tu respuesta.

Sin embargo, ten presente que la pregunta podría ser cerrada y si no obtiene votos positivos, eventualmente eliminada. Más detalles en [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/65)

Answer (score 0):

Si una pregunta es clara tiene respuesta y puede ser de ayuda para otras personas y trata sobre desarrollo y uso de software para profesionales y entusiastas entonces es una buena pregunta. No será excelente, no será la maravilla que nos gustaría ver, pero tiene la principal y fundamental cualidad de una buena pregunta: dar pie a una respuesta que sea útil para mucha gente.
Si tiene esa cualidad es una buena pregunta aunque no contenga un ejemplo mínimo y verificable, aunque no contenga lo que se ha intentado, aunque la respuesta sea trivial, aunque una búsqueda en Internet nos de la respuesta en 3 minutos.

No olvidemos el [propósito de SO en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) : 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No, el objetivo de SO no es cerrar preguntas, ni ganar puntos ni siquiera seguir las normas del sitio. Esas cosas son los **medios** que nos llevan a conseguir el objetivo: crear una biblioteca de respuestas detalladas para todas las preguntas sobre Stack Overflow en español.

Normas que en muchos casos son más consejos y guías que leyes estrictas. Y que debemos aplicar con flexibilidad para no pervertir lo realmente importante: el objetivo del sitio.

Respondiendo directamente a tu pregunta: publica tu respuesta puesto que la consideras útil.

Que la búsqueda de la excelencia no nos haga abandonar las cosas buenas.

¿Y si no es clara la pregunta? Entonces no es que no debas responderla, es que no puedes, aunque quieras. Como mucho puedes jugar al juego de las adivinanzas, pero este no es el sito para eso.

¿Y si la respuesta no sería de utilidad general? Pues entonces mejor invertir el tiempo en algo más productivo. Pero si quieres responderla nadie te lo impide (hasta que la cierren). No esperes muchos votos.

Comment: Mi duda no iba sobre una pregunta en concreto, era un tema que surgió la semana pasada y he discutido hoy pero, casualidades de la vida, justamente esta mañana me he visto en esa situación. Veo cosas a favor de tu postura pero me gustaría que en este sitio las preguntas y respuestas tuvieran la mayor calidad posible, el problema que veo en responder antes de tiempo es que es raro que se edite la pregunta una vez que ya esta respondida (aunque hoy mismo he pedido a un OP que lo hiciera después de aceptar una respuesta y me ha hecho caso), no está todo perdido :)

Comment: El riesgo de responder de todas formas es jugar a las adivinanzas... me parece que no hay forma de *no* jugarlo si se responden preguntas que no cumplen con los requisitos.

Comment: @g3rv4 A veces si está claro lo que se pregunta pero no hay código ni investigación

Comment: El tema de la flexibilidad, el aplicar unas normas a veces sí a veces no, es que es subjetivo. Y donde unos ven un claro caso de SÍ, otros podrán ver un rotundo NO... Entonces, cómo unificar criterios? Es difícil. Siguiendo las reglas al pie de la letra se puede llegar al mismo fin, aunque tardemos más, lo haremos bien.