# Comportamiento ante respuestas a preguntas de baja calidad

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales, respuesta, calidad-de-publicaciones

En esta pregunta: [¿Comó comparar dos fechas en Javascript únicamente por la fecha?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/100320/19610) he observado que se han votado negativamente a las respuestas, pese a que son perfectamente válidas y correctas.

En los comentarios, se argumenta que el voto negativo **a las respuestas** ha sido motivado por el hecho de responder a una pregunta de baja calidad, que no mostraba el esfuerzo previo realizado por el OP (antes de las ediciones).

Sin embargo, el sitio dispone de la medalla [Reversión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal), otorgada por dar **buenas respuestas** a **malas preguntas**. Lo cual me hace pensar que las respuestas han de votarse **por la propia calidad de las mismas**, independientemente de la calidad de la pregunta que las genera.

Así pues, me surge la duda: ¿ Como actuar ante respuestas **de calidad** en preguntas de baja calidad ?

Comment: A mi eso no me parece bien. Estoy de acuerdo en no contestar  preguntas de baja calidad pero votar en contra de buenas respuestas como castigo creo que es contraproducente. Yo opto por comentar en las respuestas y votar en contra de la pregunta.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo actuar con preguntas de baja calidad?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2603/7176)

Comment: Como siempre: [Votemos por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83) ni cualquier otro motivo.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/958/227)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para contestar la pregunta en forma clara y conscisa, la forma en que debemos actuar es la siguiente:

- Para las respuestas, votar positivo si la respuesta "es útil" tal y como lo indica [Votar Positivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) y votar negativo si la respuesta "no es útil", tal y como lo indica [Votar Negativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Cito textualmente del último articulo:

> Utiliza tu voto negativo cada vez que encuentres una pregunta o
>   respuesta atrozmente descuidada, poco rigurosa, sin ningún esfuerzo
>   empleado, o que es clara, pero quizás peligrosamente incorrecta.

De manera que, el voto en la respuesta no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con el contenido de la pregunta. Asi que, si la respuesta 1) exhibe razón alguna para votar negativo, hazlo o 2) exhibe razón para votar positivo, hazlo.

De la misma manera que respuestas malas reciben votos negativos en una buena pregunta, en una pregunta mala pueden existir respuestas que reciban votos positivos, lo cual evidencia que los votos en las preguntas y respuestas no tienen relación alguna.

---

**Mi opinion con el contexto de la pregunta mencionada**

Una posible justificación para votar negativo cuando la pregunta no cumple con los requerimientos establecidos, sería que es porque existe mas probabilidad de que las respuestas dadas no solucionen el problema, ciertamente porque no se sabe cual es el problema en concreto, lo cual convierte las respuestas en incorrectas, y por lo tanto existe cierto respaldo para votar negativo.

Lo que yo hago personalmente es indicar al que respondió que espere para que le pregunta mejore. Si ya esta publicada la respuesta, generalmente pido que no lo haga en el futuro y que cuando exista clarificación del OP que edite su respuesta.

Pienso que estas situaciones se dan porque los usuarios estan en busca de reputación en vez de ayudar, y piensan que con una respuesta fácil y rápida aumenta su probabilidad de recibir votos positivos o de que su respuesta sea marcada como aceptada.

En vez de castigar con votos negativos, eduquemos a los usuarios a no hacerlo en el futuro y hacer uso de las funciones de edición y comentarios para mejorar ambas publicaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Respondo a esta discusión ya que fui yo quien votó negativamente a la pregunta y las respuestas dadas en sus primeras ediciones. La pregunta inicial me parece que no cumplía en absoluto las *reglas básicas* de una pregunta buena o decente, para ser el caso, me parece que no cumplía con esto: [**Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Sinceramente no pensé que mis acciones fueran a terminar en medio de una discusión en *SOes Meta*, pero de todas maneras explicaré más a detalle el porqué de mis acciones y lo que realicé posteriormente a la edición de la pregunta y las respuestas.

[*(Véase aquí la revisión de ediciones de dicha pregunta).*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/100320/revisions)

### Inicialmente la pregunta fue esta:

> **¿Comó comparar dos fechas en Javascript únicamente por la fecha?**
>
> Hola tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo un conjunto de pares de fechas provenientes de diferentes eventos, las cuales deseo comparar con la fecha actual.
>
> Para los tipos **Date**, *JavaScript* soporta los operadores `>, <, ===, !==, >=, <=`. Para la comparación compara la fecha completa incluyendo fecha y horas que es lo correcto pero, aquí es donde surge mi problema ya que solo estoy necesitando comparar únicamente las fechas, sin contemplar la hora.

En este punto, voté negativo a la pregunta por las siguientes razones:

- El autor no publicó un ejemplo de lo que tenía.
- No veía un mínimo intento de solución por parte del usuario.
- No me quedaba claro el formato de las fechas que tenía.
- No me quedaba claro el formato de las fechas que quería comparar.
- Porque cuando realicé dos simples búsquedas en *Google*:

  > "How to compare dates in JavaScript?"
  >   "¿Cómo comparar fechas en JavaScript?"

El primer enlace que encontré fue de una pregunta en SOen [How to compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript), en la cual hay una cantidad bastante decente de muy buenas respuestas.

Y el segundo fue de un artículo bastante completo y muy bien explicado totalmente en español [Comparar fechas en JavaScript](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/comparar-fechas-javascript.html).

A las respuestas dadas les voté negativo porque me parece que responder a una pregunta de baja calidad es ayudar a la mediocridad de los usuarios que no se esfuerzan por solucionar su propio problema antes de venir aquí a pedir un poco de ayuda más específica (como se puede ver en el último punto anterior simplemente con dos búsquedas en internet.

### Cuando el autor editó la pregunta

> Hola tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo un conjunto de pares de fechas provenientes de diferentes eventos, las cuales deseo comparar con una fecha especifica.
>
> Para los tipos **Date**, Javascript soporta los operadores `>, <, ===, !==, >=, <=` para la comparación compara la fecha completa incluyendo fecha y horas que es lo correcto pero, aquí es donde surge mi problema ya que solo estoy necesitando comparar únicamente las fechas sin contemplar la hora.
>
> Simplifico el problema en un ejemplo sencillo:
>
> ```js
> let inicio = new Date('2017-09-06T20:56:51');
> let fin = new Date('2017-09-06T20:56:53');
> // Fecha a comparar si se encuentra en el rango
> let comparador = new Date('2017-09-06T12:56:53');
> // Aquí es el problema
> let resultado = inicio <= comparador && fin >= comparador
> ```

Si comparara únicamente por fechas omitiendo la hora, `resultado` devolvería `true`.

Creo que la diferencia es evidentemente clara y concisa mostrando mucho mejor su problema, los formatos que tiene y lo que quiere, en este punto retiré mi voto negativo tanto en la pregunta como en las respuestas, ya que la pregunta mostraba un problema específico, con un ejemplo y la información necesaria para ser una buena pregunta.

**Pido disculpas a la comunidad, de ante mano, si mi actuar no fue del todo correcto o no lo hice de la mejor manera.**

Comment: Me agrada que tomes la responsabilidad y respaldes tus acciones, +1 por eso. Creo que tu respuesta sería aun mejor si contestas las pregunta de ¿como actuar ante preguntas de calidad en preguntas de baja calidad?

Comment: No tienes que pedir disculpas, cada uno vota según su criterio y puede hacerlo como quiera. Entiendo tu postura, contestar preguntas de mala calidad puede dar pie a que la gente no se preocupe por elaborarlas mejor porque siempre obtienen solución. Tambien está el tema de que es mala calidad exactamente, cada uno pone los límites en lugares diferentes.

Comment: Opino igual que blonfu. Actuaste según tu criterio, claramente definido (que yo puedo o no compartir); con esta pregunta, no pretendo cuestionarlo. Solo aspiro a obtener una *guía a seguir* ante estos casos.