# Montones de preguntas de muy baja calidad (y respuestas igualmente malas)

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Estamos notando (segun lo venimos hablando en el chat) de la pobre calidad de las preguntas, y la pobre calidad de las respuestas, no ya solo de usuarios nuevos (los cuales puede que no sepan como preguntar) si no de usuarios con cierta reputacion en el sitio.

Voy a tomar una pregunta que salio recien, pero solo como ejemplo:

[¿Qué significa la interrogación después del tipo de dato?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139736/que-significa-declarar-una-variable-de-esta-forma-private-decimal-monto?noredirect=1#comment260938_139736)

La pregunta de por si es mala, y se soluciona con cualquier busquea en google.

Lo peor de esto, es el apuro de muchos usuarios por contestar dicha pregunta (veanse las respuestas) y despues los mismos usuarios quejandose por los votos negativos (en este caso, yo solo vote la pregunta).

Estas respuestas no deberian ni haber aparecido por estos usuarios. Tiene suficiente reputacion para saber que la pregunta es mala.

Sin embargo, valga como ejemplo la anterior, se esta notando una catarata de malas preguntas que son contestadas antes de tiempo, y eso provoca una baja generalizada en la calidad de las mismas.

[GENERAR LETRAS ALEATORIAS EN C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139285/generar-letras-aleatorias-en-c/139299#139299)

OP se queja que es nuevo, pero sigue sin leer los links de como funciona el sitio. La respuesta en este caso es de un usuario nuevo, lo cual lo perdona un poco. Pero ya tenemos otra mala pregunta con una mala respuesta.

[Regular expression](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138568/regular-expression/138602#138602)

En este caso, la pregunta nunca se completo por mas que se le pidio a OP que lo hiciera. Para peor, quien contesto, contesto al boleo, y critico a quien le remarco que su respuesta fue demasiado rapido.

Asi podriamos pasarnos toda la tarde. Aquellos que estan dando vueltas por el sitio seguido, lo deben estar notando. No se si esto ayuda a levantar el sitio, o lo hunde mas, porque nos obliga a castigar a los usuarios nuevos mas severamente, por culpa de usuarios con cierta reputacion que hacen las cosas como si fueran nuevos.

[SQL SERVER. Campo booleano de una lista ordenada alfabeticamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138232/sql-server-campo-booleano-de-una-lista-ordenada-alfabeticamente/138566#138566)

En este caso, se le pidio a OP varias veces, que completara y aclarara su pregunta. Parecia abandonada. Sin embargo se corrio a darle dos respuestas. Una mala y la otra correcta, pero apurada, porque no sabemos si es lo que necesita OP o no.

Esta bien que el aspecto ludico del sitio lleva a este tipo de cosas. Pero aquellos que tenemos mas reputacion no deberiamos ser mucho mas estrictos?

Podemos ser permisivos con cualquiera que no tenga mas de 200 de rep. Pero cualquier otro que se desvia, no deberia ser castigado? No hablo de algo radical, si no con las herramientas que da el sitio, como los votos negativos, que se que se usan para calificar las respuestas, pero como tambien se usan para medir la confiabilidad de un usuario, no deberia ser castigado?

La inquietud es, como podemos hacer para castigar a los usuarios con cierta reputacion, como podemos guiar a los nuevos usuarios y como podemos hacer que el sitio suba la calidad que esta teniendo, para no transformarse en yahoo respuestas?

### Edición/Aclaración

Esto no es un ataque personal contra ninguna de las preguntas/respuestas, si no algunos ejemplos. Podria haber usado otros, y tambien podria haber agregado muchos mas. Algunos seran un claro ejemplo de lo que digo, otros podrán ser cuestionables, pero la idea es mostrar como sin querer estamos haciendo que baje la calidad y no moderando con eficiencia.

### Mas ejemplos (y apoyo el triage)

[Como mostrar matriz triangulo superior derecho java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140632/como-mostrar-matriz-triangulo-superior-derecho-java)

Una hora perdida, 3 personas desde el chat. No habia forma de hacerle entender a OP como arreglar su pregunta. No es la primera que hace.

[Como optimizar consulta sql?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140544/como-optimizar-consulta-sql/)

Una pregunta que empezo siendo una cosa, tuvo 3 respuestas que no era lo que queria, molesto a varios usuarios nuevos que trataron de contestarle, para que al final diga que lo hizo solo, con una respuesta que no se entiende y no contesta la pregunta. Patricio puso una respuesta que salvaria la pregunta, si no fuera porque realmente esta contestando algo generico y no la pregunta en si.

Comment: Yo me pongo un poco pasional cuando es una de [tag:regex] y se me van los estribos :-( ... Exageré un poco con los comentarios... Pero en esta no me ayudaban a cerrarla. Tuve esa pestaña abierta por 2 días.

Comment: Sabés, no sé si es tan buen ejemplo el primero que pusiste. Tuve que leer tu pregunta varias veces para darme cuenta de esto, porque no estaba tan de acuerdo con esa primera pregunta: empezás hablando de usuarios con "*cierta reputacion*", pero ese usuario tiene 112, que juntó a lo largo de más de un año, remando en dulce de leche, sumando un ocasional +5 por pregunta y +2 por aceptación, con muchas preguntas que todos le ignoraron y se terminó respondiendo solo. Es uno de los niños de la trilogía JS-jQuery-Laravel y esa era su primera pregunta en C# (que yo no cerraría). Nada que ver el resto

Comment: Si hago preguntas sobre un lenguaje que nadie usa, tambien la voy a remar en dulce de leche. Igual en esa primera pregunta es mas preocupante el accionar de los que responden que la pregunta en si. Si cuesta entender el punto, tal vez deba refrasear la pregunta (me refiero a esta pregunta).

Comment: Y sobre esa pregunta las dos respuestas son malas. Recien revisamo c# en profundidad. Y skeet escribio un capitulo entero sobre tipos nullables (el ? Es sugar syntaxis).

Comment: No perdamos de vista que es válido responder a preguntas malas, de hecho hay una medalla cuando se obtienen un número alto de votos positivos en una respuesta a una  mala pregunta. Una pregunta clara puede ser mala por no incluir una descripción de lo buscado/investigado entre otros motivos y siendo clara se puede responder de manera coherente, pero una pregunta que no es clara es prácticamente imposible de responder así, por lo que si se publica una respuesta muy problema te merezca votos negativos.

Comment: Si respondemos a "preguntas malas", he notado que los OP continúan realizando preguntas con este mismo patrón, una breve explicación, no agregan código, no agregan nada especifico en la pregunta. Incluso generalmente estas "preguntas malas" son demasiado amplias y si una usuario agrega una respuesta que en realidad no resuelve el "problema" especificado en la pregunta, en ocasiones el OP la marca como correcta :-/, aportando a la baja calidad de información en el sitio. Considero que lo mejor es guiar a los OP a realizar preguntas de acuerdo a lo especificado en el [help].

Comment: Yo no soy partidario de votar negativo a buenas respuestas aunque la pregunta sea mala, ya lo dije en esta otra pregunta: [Comportamiento ante respuestas a preguntas de baja calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2772/comportamiento-ante-respuestas-a-preguntas-de-baja-calidad#comment9506_2772). Mi opción sería comentarlo, hacer ver a quien responde que no es bueno contestar malas preguntas si queremos un sitio de calidad.

Answer (score 3):

> En mi defensa a la respuesta que brinde a la pregunta [SQL SERVER. Campo booleano de una lista ordenada alfabeticamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/138232/45) (favor de considerar las fechas de la pregunta y mi respuesta).

---

Primero, el sitio de Stack Overflow es de preguntas y respuestas, por ende no encontrarás usuarios que quieran ser parte de la comunidad porque quizás solo busquen una solución a su problema, y si no la encuentran aquí la encontrarán en otro lugar. La solución que brindé es porque sencillamente entendí la pregunta y tiene lo necesario para ser respondida, asimismo, **es un incentivo para que el OP tome más interés en el sitio como lo hice en las varias preguntas que respondí**.

Segundo, el por qué considero que tiene lo necesario, es por lo siguiente:

1. Tiene un título que explica lo que necesita.
2. En el cuerpo de la pregunta explica lo que tiene actualmente y el resultado esperado. Detalla que tiene una tabla Persona con dichas columnas y que se encuentran ordenadas alfabeticamente, pero quiere agregar una columna que identifique si es primero (revisar su cuadro).
3. La tecnología que usa: [sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) [sql-server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)

Por último, respondiendo a los comentarios agregados a la pregunta.

> **Raul Cacacho:**
>
> - Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar la consulta que tienes ya
> - Puedes hacerlo con un case

*R. El resultado que ya obtiene de su consulta se basa en lo que describe en la pregunta. Quizás para algunos sería necesario que el OP agregue algo como `SELECT PAIS, CIUDAD, NOMBRE, EDAD FROM PERSONA ORDER BY PAIS, CIUDAD, NOMBRE` para que entiendan la estructura de la tabla. Pero en mi caso no es así. Y al decir "Puedes hacerlo con un case", vi que el comentario más bien lo manda al desvío.*

> **Millán:**
>
> - Si adicionas la consulta te podemos ayudar modificandola como la necesites, sin embargo, te doy una idea, en el select puedes adicionar un columna y sobre ella una subconsulta, o un join. No conocemos bien la estructura de su base de datos

*R. Ídem que lo anterior.*

> **Gianchi:**
>
> - Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
> - Si mostras lo que intentaste hasta ahora, podemos ayudarte a encontrar una solucion.

*R. Como parte de la comunidad estamos en la necesidad de moderar, de lo cuál ya lo hiciste en esos 3 días (desde la publicación de la pregunta hasta mi respuesta). Y nuevamente Ídem que lo primero.*

---

> Sería muy hermoso que en nuestra comunidad haya preguntas que sean de gran calidad, pero en la realidad habrá personas que solo quieren una solución a sus problemas y por ende visitan stack**overflow**, y es en ese tránsito que al responder una pregunta, al cuál entendiste y en tu criterio tiene lo necesario, captar al nuevo para que sea parte de la comunidad y esperar su participación.

*PD. A las personas de los votos negativos, espero su participación y explicarme el por qué.*

Comment: Yo no te voté negativo, no conocía la pregunta hasta ahora, pero entiendo porqué recibiste esos votos. La cuestión aqui (y esta es mi opinión personal, que puede ser acertada o equivocada) no es si entiendes o no la pregunta.En numerosas ocasiones, la pregunta puede estar clarísima, pero el OP no ha mostrado ningún esfuerzo por resolver el problema, y ninguna respuesta a los comentarios que le pedían mejorar la pregunta. En esos casos, creo que es mejor no responder hasta que al menos el OP de señales de vida.

Comment: Yo tampoco te vote negativo, opte por "quejarme" de tu respuesta. Igual ya aclare en la pregunta que esto no es personal contra nadie, si no una generalidad y tu respuesta cayo en esta pregunta de casualidad, como le podia haber pasado a cualquier otro. La idea es entender que si hubiera sido una buena pregunta, con seguimiento de OP y todo (o mala, pero el OP la seguia, y podiamos arreglarla), entonces si valia la pena tratar de contestarsela. Esa pregunta, sin seguimiento, sin respuesta aceptada, sin nada, va a terminar perdida.