# ¿Se puede o no responder a preguntas mal formuladas?

Tags: soporte, respuesta

Buen día Comunidad de Meta SOes.

En base a la respuesta que he dado a la siguiente pregunta formulada en SOes:
 [Librería pdf para HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170954/libreria-pdf-para-php/170961#170961)

Me gustaría saber exactamente cuando se puede responder a una pregunta y cuando no, es decir, a mi entender (y según esta [pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2772/comportamiento-ante-respuestas-a-preguntas-de-baja-calidad) formulada aquí mismo en Meta) el hecho de que la pregunta esté mal formulada no me impide dar una respuesta útil que sirva a otros usuarios de referencia para resolver una duda similar sin que estos incurran en realizar la misma pregunta mal formulada (o una parecida a ella).

> Además tomando en cuenta que el sitio premia a sus usuarios con la medalla de
>   reversión que justamente impulsa a responder una pregunta puntuada 
>   negativamente y obtener +20 en la respuesta... No me
>   termina de quedar claro si puedo o no responder a este tipo de
>   preguntas.

Me parece contraproducente que por realizar una acción estimulada por el sistema de reconocimientos del sitio castiguen mi respuesta puntuandola negativamente. La línea que diferencia los premios de las reglas en este caso parece muy delgada y presta a malas interpretaciones.

> Como efecto colateral a mi pregunta menciono cuando se daría el caso
>   de ganar la medalla de **reversión**? si la pregunta cumple con las reglas
>   del sitio entonces dificilmente sea puntuada negativamente y sumado a
>   esto si no se debe responder a preguntas que no cumplan con las reglas
>   del sitio... entonces cuando un usuario gana esta medalla?
>   no es cierto que en base a todo lo mencionado anteriormente la medalla 
>   **reversión** carece de sentido o uso práctico?

Planteo esto para tener conocimiento sobre si estoy cometiendo un error porque de ser así lo tomo en cuenta para futuras preguntas como esta y evitar responderlas.

Espero puedan colaborarme. Un saludo!

Comment: El problema con esa pregunta es que se basa en opiniones, puede ser una pregunta mal formulada pero que entre en la temática del sitio. Esa pregunta para mi parecer no entraría.

Comment: Si @KacosPro tienes toda la razón. El Sr Montoro me estuvo explicando en la misma pregunta y ya me queda claro que no debo responder a ellas. Mi duda gira más en torno a la medalla de reversión. Debería cambiarle el título a tiene sentido la medalla reversión? que te parecería?

Comment: Hace un tiempo hubo una duda sobre una pregunta que tenía votos negativos mientras la respuesta aceptada tenía bastantes puntos positivos. Era algo sobre un problema matemático. Cuando llegue a un ordenador la busco y la enlazo.

Comment: Si @AlvaroMontoro como le decia a Kacos ya entendí por qué no debo responder a ese tipo de preguntas. Me parece que debo cambiar el título a esta pregunta ya que como dice Kacos no es mal formulada y mi duda tiene que ver más con la medalla reversión y el significado que da a una pregunta puntuada negativamente

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De poder se puede, pero no se recomienda. Ref. [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Al responder una mala pregunta, además de correr el riesgo de que tu respuesta se pierda si el OP decide borrar su pregunta, ref. [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/65), corres el riesgo de recibir votos negativos de quienes no ven bien que se responda a las malas preguntas. El nivel de riesgo varía mucho de etiqueta a etiqueta. Algunas atraen a usuarios muy exigentes mientras que otras rara vez son vistas.

En lo personal pienso que las respuestas se deben juzgar independientemente de la pregunta, sin embargo hay un aspecto que no se puede desvincular el cual es que **la respuesta responda a la pregunta**, y si la pregunta no es clara esto es imposible. Si encuentras una mala pregunta, consideras que no tiene arreglo pero aún así te inspira a escribir una buena respuesta, entonces considera publicar una pregunta auto-respondida.

En cuanto a la medalla reversión, es una medalla de plata porque no es nada sencillo obtenerla, sin embargo, tampoco es tan fuertemente impulsado como otras cosas y pues ahí queda como medalla de plata, no de oro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. El Sr. Montoro también me explicó justo en la pregunta que anexé y me ha quedado claro mi duda estaba un poco más dirigida a la medalla de reversión. Pero ya me ha quedado claro con su explicación muchas gracias Sr Rubén y disculpe la molestia

Comment: Ya no respondo más a este tipo de preguntas. Sencillamente le haré saber al OP su falla (bueno yo tampoco sabía que estuviese cometiendo una). Me queda de aprendizaje. Gracias nuevamente Sr Rubén. Definitivamente me quedo con su consejo de publicar una pregunta auto-respondida

Comment: Esa pregunta es muy representativa de lo que algunos consideran una pregunta poco concreta y precisa y lo que otros pueden considerar lo contrario. Y a veces, en mi opinion, por falta de conocimientos sobre el tema, se toma demasiado a la ligera si la pregunta es o no concreta, porque ni se sabe que pregunta y las posibles respuestas (o respuesta) que ella tiene. Otra cosa es considerar que todas las preguntas tienen que estar basadas en poner un código para que te digan donde esta el error, porque entonces también podría ocurrir lo que se intenta evitar. Ejemplo: códigos con errores léxicos.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga

Comment: "corres el riesgo de recibir votos negativos" ... si fuera sólo por puntos estaríamos todos contestando preguntas básicas de javascript o sql, o marcando como duplicado cuando la respuesta aceptada (en el duplicado) es nuestra. No creo que SO como empresa tenga problemas de almacenamiento: si la pregunta y la respuesta son muy puntuales y referidas a un problema que nadie mas en el universo va encontrarse jamás se perderán en el limbo, o no. ref obligada https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 5):

## Sí, siempre.

Y no dejes que nadie te diga lo contrario. No causas ningún daño respondiendo una pregunta, no perjudicas la calidad del sitio ni animas a que se hagan malas preguntas.

Seguro que hay mejores maneras de contribuir al sitio. Pero tu tiempo es tuyo y solo tu decides qué hacer con él.

Jay Hanlon, un empleado de SO, lo explica mejor que yo en su blog en inglés [StackOverflow no es muy acogedor. Es hora de que eso cambie.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)

> Y pocas cosas me entristecen más que comentarios en respuestas
> diciendo, "No respondas preguntas como estas - estás promoviéndolas."
> Sí, algunas están fuera de lugar. (Lo siento de verdad, pero
> simplemente no podemos explicar por qué una jarra de cristal puede
> atravesar un muro de ladrillos sin roturas aparentes; somos un sitio
> de programación.) Pero es totalmente guay responder a preguntas sin dar
> un bocadillo de mierda asada sobre lo que se permite exactamente. Está
> bien ofrecerse voluntario de alguna manera sin que se espere haber
> leído y hacer cumplir cada regla y discusión en meta desde el inicio de los
> tiempos.

Comment: Y también vimos las [reacciones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/welcoming) que ese post tuvo en la comunidad ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte

Comment: `ni animas a que se hagan malas preguntas.` Completamente en desacuerdo. Quien hizo la pregunta tiene lo que quería, la próxima vez que le convenga hará exactamente lo mismo y no se esforzará lo más mínimo en cambiar.

Comment: @SJuan76 Eso no es cierto. Es posible dar una buena respuesta con la información necesaria para responder una mala pregunta en la que se enseña a programar la solución en vez de dar una solución de copiar y pegar. Por ejemplo [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82932/301) que era un respuesta a una pregunta no muy buena; la pregunta fue borrada y yo la republiqué con una mejor redacción pero sin cambiar la respuesta. Esa respuesta solo le sirve a quien quiera esforzarse y no le sirve a quien solo quiere copiar y pegar.

Comment: Si hay preguntas que puedes responder, hazlo.  Si las preguntas salen malas, los moderadores se encargarán de ellas al igual que con las respuestas.

Comment: @SEinfringescopyright, muy aporte. Estuve leyendo la reflexión de **Jay Hanlon**. Me parece genial.