# ¿Por qué no existe penalización a quien le haga la tarea a un usuario nuevo?

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales, calidad-de-publicaciones

Llevo más de un año en Stack Overflow, y a lo largo de eso he visto en más de una ocasión que existen preguntas mal realizadas según lo establecido.

En ellas solo se coloca lo que requiere, más sin embargo no lo que ha intentado. Si bien hay quienes cordialmente sugieren dar un recorrido en cómo preguntar, hay quienes prácticamente le hacen la "tarea".

Considero que por acciones como estas, varios usuarios no construyen adecuadamente las preguntas y limitan su apertura de conocimiento. De igual forma comprendo que hay usuarios nuevos que responden las preguntas por ganar reputación.

Así como se penaliza con votos negativos a quienes no estructuran adecuadamente su pregunta, ¿por qué no hay una penalización mayor a quienes le hacen la tarea y más con una reputación considerable?

Comment: En general se los penaliza, mucha gente les da votos negativos a respuestas a preguntas que no cumplen con las normas.. Desgraciadamente, a veces son muy buenas respuestas a malas preguntas. Yo trato de recordarles siempre a los usuarios que no contesten dichas preguntas, pero no esta en mi andar borrando respuestas porque si.

Comment: Te agrego otro ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/263452/324

Comment: Lo otro que podemos hacer.. es no dar un segundo de respiro y cerrarlas inmediatamente.. Lo estoy haciendo con algunas avisandole a AP que me avise cuando la arregle. No sucedio nunca hasta ahora. Pero van a  tratar a los moderadores de autoritarios :/

Comment: A mi parecer, si bien generalmente una mala pregunta tiende a tener una mala respuesta, no siempre es el caso, y en algunas ocasiones (como la del ejemplo que planteas) muy buenas.. Si bien el OP no parece haber intentado nada, el día de mañana, quien caiga en una problemática similar, tendrá una respuesta a la cual llegar, y en definitiva, eso es lo que buscamos no? Ser una base de datos de problemas de programación

Comment: @gbianchi ¿realmente un moderador debería estar señalando ejemplos de preguntas malas? Cuidado con el efecto meta

Comment: @gbianchi, igual es un poco molesta la penalización de parte de los usuarios, participe en una de las respuestas del link que dices, y esa misma información el OP si la puede encontrar en cualquier otro Blog, foro etc, pero como dice Juan Salvador Portugal, esta comunidad es la que tiene que tener esa información, he participado en muchas respuestas a preguntas básicas y a esas preguntas Copy paste de la tarea del OP, siempre recomendando modificar la pregunta, exigiéndoles código de lo que han realizado. En este caso otros usuarios le pidieron al OP actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: @Ikabod entiendo tu problema, pero fijate que una vez contestada, muchos de los que preguntan sin tomarse el trabajo de hacer algo, abandonan la pregunta. Entonces contestarle y pedirle que la mejore, es una doble via que en la mayoria de los casos no llega a ningun lado.

Comment: En cuanto a la pregunta concuerdo, existen veces que a los usuarios mas novatos no se les pide o exige que mejoren la calidad de la pregunta o que agreguen alguna información detallada de lo que necesitan, simplemente se responde enseguida para poder tener mas reputación, en ese caso para los usuarios que ya tienen una reputación considerable y no exigen esto claramente existe un problema con este tipo de usuario, se debe penalizar?, yo creo que si pero cada caso es aparte y estar preocupándose de que los usuarios con mas reputación tengan estas buenas practicas debe ser un lió.

Comment: @gbianchi, claramente eso es lo otro los usuarios nuevos tienen una tendencia de abandonar la pregunta, que también es molesto, por que yo se que hay muchas personas que se toman el tiempo de dar una buena respuesta explicando el por que de la cosas, desde que estoy en stackoverflow siempre pero siempre se han presentado problemas con los usuarios nuevos. por algo me imagino que se han creado cosas como la manito que te dice NUEVO COLABORADOR, pero siguen existiendo problemas, que no se que tanto pueden ser controlados.

Comment: Y yo me sigo preguntando.. que impide a alguien que ve una muy mala pregunta, que se puede arreglar o hasta se puede repreguntar, hacerlo y poner su respuesta alli? porque ya que se toman el tiempo en escribir una respuesta, no se toman tambien el tiempo en arreglar la pregunta o cerrarla como poco clara, y poner una pregunta propia al respecto? Creo que la parte ludica pesa mucho en ese sentido.

Comment: @gbianchi, entiendo lo que dices, pero también existe una revisión de pares al editar la pregunta, si el OP no hace nada quedamos donde mismo empezamos, esto se le puede pedir a algún admin ? digo para que pueda validar los cambios que se le hicieron a la pregunta?

Comment: Si, pero tene en cuenta que no necesariamente saben del tema y pueden editar la pregunta como para que se entienda que se quiso decir. Nadie mejor que quien dio una gran respuesta para editar la pregunta y arreglarla si corresponde. Aunque yo seguiria optando por escribir otra pregunta si AP no aparece en un corto tiempo.

Comment: @gbianchi, lo que dices lo entiendo, no digo que el OP edite la pregunta, no fue a lo que quise llegar con mi comentario, lo que quise decir es que en el enlace que posteaste edite la pregunta del usuario para que se pudiera entender, pero aun así hay que esperar la revisión de pares.

Comment: Y esta perfecto.. pero fijate lo que va a pasar... AP nunca va a aceptar la respuesta. La pregunta esta abandonada.. y le cambiaste totalmente el sentido a lo que pregunto. Entonces.. no es mejor hacer otra pregunta y que quede bien formada y con seguimiento? no va a haber ninguna respuesta aceptada en esa pregunta.

Comment: Si bien lo ideal es que haya respuestas aceptadas no es tan importante como el haya votos. En muchos casos la respuesta aceptada no tiene tantos votos como otras y en los peores de los casos incluso es mala y en los no tan peores hay respuestas aceptadas con puntuación negativa.

Comment: entonces @gbianchi si edito la pregunta adaptándola a mi respuesta me la darían por buena, porque yo pensaba que eso no se podía hacer, de ser asi la edito segun lo que me responda. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/509228/procedimiento-mysql-que-utiliza-valor-en-tabla-como-dato

Comment: @JavierG.Raya toda esta conversacion dice EXACTAMENTE lo contrario.. no modifiques una pregunta para que tu respuesta encaje.. aca se habla de mejorar la pregunta, no de modificarla para que tu respuesta tenga sentido... Porque no haces una pregunta que vaya con tu respuesta y agregas tu respuesta ahi y listo?

Comment: Vale muchas gracias

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Siendo aludido por tu publicación, ya que soy uno de quienes ha respondido a la pregunta que pones de ejemplo, te comparto mi punto de vista.

## Hilando más fino

Lo primero que te pido es que hagamos una separación un poco más *fina* a la hora de clasificar las preguntas.

Hablando de la **solicitud de hacer una tarea escolar** sin demostrar ningún esfuerzo, en mi opinión, esta pregunta se caracteríza porque el AP generalmente copia y pega el enunciado de la tarea, sin demostrar ningún esfuerzo o intento por solucionarla por si mismo, independientemente de la complejidad que tenga esta tarea y por tanto, muchas veces son preguntas que no son aceptables en el sitio, también, porque no está claro lo que se pregunta, porque son muy amplias y por otras razones, no por el simple hecho de ser una tarea escolar.

Hay también preguntas que son sobre temas tan simple, en el que realmente no hay mucho que demostrar como *esfuerzo* para resolver, pues el mínimo esfuerzo, daría con la solución del problema y probablemente la pregunta nunca existiría. Este tipo de preguntas suelen ser preguntas que, fuera de si son planteadas por un estudiante que solo quiere haceer su tarea, por un entusiasta que está aprendiendo a programar o un nuevo lenguaje de programación, o por un profesional que de pronto se ve enfrentado a un lenguaje esotérico o desconocido, suelen ser preguntas que son aceptables en el sitio. Es decir, preguntan algo concreto de manera suficientemente clara para poder ser respondidas.

Estos dos conjuntos de preguntas, claro está, en ocasiones se traslapan.

[image: Diagrama de venn]

Yo respondo únicamente preguntas del segundo grupo, que he marcado en mi diagrama en color para mayor claridad.

Podemos considerar estas preguntas como de baja calidad, aunque hay algunas francamente interesantes y bien planteadas, aunque sea en dos pequeñas líneas de texto, sin código. Yo veo en estas una **gran oportunidad** y las utilizo como pretexto para dotar a StackOverflow de contenido que, estoy convencido, ayudará a muchas personas en el futuro, a las que hagan algo de esfuerzo de investigación, pues podrán encontrar explicaciones y ejemplos de buena calidad para su formación académica, profesional o personal.

Algunas personas de la comunidad, consideran que esto debe ser castigado y me dan votos negativos cuando lo hago. [Mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/263512/21) a la pregunta que tu dejas como ejemplo no es la excepción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, considero que actúo dentro de las normas y respeto la opinión de todos, por tanto, nunca me he quejado de esos votos negativos. Yo estoy en mi derecho de responder, y la comunidad en su derecho de expresarse con sus votos al respecto de mis aportes.

Finalmente

## ¿Cuál es el objetivo de StackOverflow?

Considero que el objetivo del sitio es construir la mayor base de datos en español de preguntas y respuestas sobre programación, en todos los lenguajes y temáticas posibles.

Desde este punto de vista, las preguntas son solo el medio (y la brùjula) por el cual construimos, entre todos, este gran repositorio de información.

Un saludo.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo contigo. Considero que muchas veces los programadores novatos (yo uno) muchas veces no somos capaces de seguir tutoriales de páginas web debido a que no sabemos modificar el código para incluir la pequeña modificación que nosotros deseamos. La solución es esa diferenciación. Y una vez entramos en la burbuja azul, yo actuaría de la siguiente forma: Alguien experimentado que de una respuesta correcta y que modifique la pregunta en el sentido de que sea la mejor "idea" para que si en un futuro alguien busca eso, SOes sea el primero en los SEOs.

Comment: Okay! Totalmente de acuerdo contigo con el objetivo de StackOverflow, sin embargo considero que debemos permitir que algunos (me incluyo) desarrollemos conocimientos sólidos, realizando esfuerzos por resolver las diferentes problemáticas que se presenten. Ya que en muchas ocasiones cortar y pegar código solo nos enseña a eso: cortar y pegar.

Comment: Mi opinión sobre este tipo de [programador copiar y pegar](https://jachguate.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/el-programador-copiar-y-pegar/) es esa, que te enlazo. Lamentablemente siempre habrá alguien así.

Comment: @YSCGProJ, creeme que entiendo tu punto. Cada vez que decido responder una pregunta de este tipo analizo a conciencia si debo hacerlo o no. Quizás la principal diferencia es que tu te estás centrando en la ayuda que se le pueda dar al AP al negarle una respuesta, y yo, en la ayuda que puedan obtener otras personas a través de la misma.

Comment: Si el AP quiere solo copiar y pegar, encontrará la manera de hacerlo, en SO o de un compañero de clase. Si quiere aprender, analizará el código de la respuesta y de todas formas aprenderá. Es lo que yo hice en su momento, creo que todos pasamos por el aprendizaje inicial, y lo sigo haciendo cada día, pues siempre se va aprendiendo cosas nuevas y siempre se es neófito en más temas de los que no.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta. Y efectivamente es bastante penoso que la gente vote negativamente estas respuestas, pues siempre debemos votar por la calidad de la publicación, no por cualquier otra cosa.

Answer (score 5):

Este es un tema en el que definitivamente no todos estamos de acuerdo.

Por un lado las guías oficiales del sitio recomiendan responder sólo las buenas preguntas y advierten que quien ose contravenir esta recomendación sufrirá la grave pena de la frustración sin determinar un plazo, seguramente dejando que los demonios internos del infractor sean sus verdugos. Nota al margen: acabo de ver la última temporada de Lucifer :)

La frustración a la que hace referencia las guías oficiales es presuntamente resultado del valor del tiempo invertido en la respuesta que la cual fuera eliminada como consecuencia de la eliminación de la pregunta.

Algunos no conformes con dicha pena han propuesto penas adicionales tales como que la comunidad se vuelque aplicando sendos votos negativos al modo de las prácticas aún vigentes en algunos lares como la pena de lapidación o latigazos públicos.

Justifican esto con el argumento que las malas preguntas atraen malas preguntas. Hace tiempo observé varios casos de "preguntadores en serie", quizás por ser el sitio nuevo estas malas preguntas estaban recibiendo muchas respuestas algunas en principio sorprendentemente buenas.

Por otro lado otros, al puro estilo de quien esté libre de culpa que tire la primera piedra, en particular en aquellos que existan causas atenuantes, tales como las descritas por jachguate en [su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4125/65), en los que aun siendo una mala pregunta, esta no fuera tan mala como para ser primero puesta en espera y eventualmente cerrada y posiblemente incluso eliminada. Por ejemplo, la pregunta es clara, incluye suficiente información como para determinar si las respuestas responden a ella. En estos casos luego vendría la utilidad de la respuesta y por último la excelencia por lo cual podría ser recompensada con reputación adicional a la otorgada por la puntuación de la respuesta, y en algunos limitándose la recompensa a la satisfacción de haber aportado a este mundo algo útil.

En lo personal aplaudo a quienes responden bien sin mirar a quien :)

Espero que antes de responder malas preguntas por lo menos veamos si no es duplicado de alguna otra.

También espero que los que votan, **no** usen las malas preguntas como excusa para "lapidar" las respuestas, en su lugar que las valoren por lo que aportan, utilidad y claridad.

---

jachguate trajo a colación la medalla Reversión que premia a aquellos con puntuación +20 o más en una respuesta a una pregunta con -5 o menos. Desconozco la  historia de esta medalla, pero he encontrado que la misma es causa de controversia algunos piden que se elimine otros que se mantenga. Véase [Can we retire the Reversal badge on main sites and keep it only for meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279285/289691)

También hay quienes se han dado a la tarea de encontrar esas respuestas "maravillosas" que se han perdido porque la pregunta fue eliminada. Véase [The Lost Worlds of the Reversal Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88709/289691)

No he leído con detalle los hilos anteriores ni investigado si hay algo más reciente. ¿Algunos de Uds. lo ha hecho? En cualquier caso yo creo que debemos votar las respuestas con base, primero en si responden la pregunta y luego por su utilidad, **nunca como castigo** por responder una mala pregunta.

Relacionado

- [¿Qué actitud es adecuada para estimular la buena calidad de preguntas y respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/201/65)
- [Comportamiento ante respuestas a preguntas de baja calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2772/65)
- [¿Se puede o no responder a preguntas mal formuladas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3520/65)

Comment: El problema de responder malas preguntas, es que instamos a que el usuario lo siga haciendo, si marcamos +1 una respuesta buena con base cuya pregunta fue mala entonces ¿Que calidad tendria el sitio ? , ¿Como instamos que los nuevos usuarios hagan buenas preguntas si igual la respondemos? de hecho en el tour nos enseñan [Cómo escribir  una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Eso lo menciono en , por ejemplo, "...las malas preguntas atraen malas preguntas. " También hago referencia al artículo de ayuda ligado en el comentario "... las guías oficiales del sitio recomiendan responder sólo las buenas preguntas..."

Comment: Me pregunto si la intención del comentario es reforzar mi respuesta, lo cual agradecería, o si se trata de debatir, lo cual también agradecería, sólo para poder debatir, ¿el primer comentario refuerza o refuta mi respuesta?

Comment: aclaro lo que se quiere decir master!, si era algo contrario hubiese dado una respuesta

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.

Comment: Si no se deben responder malas preguntas, ¿por qué existe la medalla [reversión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal)?

Comment: @jachguate Es pregunta retórica ¿verdad?

Comment: Claro, Rubén, es retórica. En general, me preocupo por la calidad de las preguntas y estimulo a quienes escriben malas preguntas a mejorar, pero de vez en cuando hay alguna mala pregunta que puede tener excelentes respuestas y creo que eso no es malo para el sitio.

Comment: @jachguate yo creo que la medalla reversión está diseñada para ver quién sabe utilizar el efecto meta de forma más eficiente XD

Comment: jajajajaja, @fedorqui, seguro que si, sobre todo en es.SO, pero además debe ser una respuesta a una pregunta no tan buena, de otra forma no llega. Sigo a la espera de ver quién logra obtenerla. :D

Answer (score 1):

Lo único adicional a lo que han dicho y que también tiene que ver con todo lo dicho, es que dependiendo del tipo de preguntas que se permitan, el perfil de usuario que visitará el sitio con regularidad cambia.

Si se responde bien sin mirar a quién ni qué tanto intenta resolver los problemas por sí mismo, los usuarios más experimentados (no todos, pero sí muchos) preferirán no pasar por acá porque encontrarán las mismas preguntas sencillas que no les interesan. Si se elige que SOes sea una base de conocimiento en donde todos se esfuerzan, preguntando y respondiendo, el alcance será más amplio.

Esto lo digo porque en el sitio original se dio la misma discusión. Cada term, llegan los que están haciendo tareas a traer enunciados o a decir "miré y no encontré nada, ¿me ayudan?"

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que en que si no hay preguntas interesantes para los expertos cuando lo visiten perderán el interés pero uno de los grandes problemas es que lo que es interesante es completamente subjetivo.

Comment: @Rubén y con esto, evades el punto del mensaje. Pero bueno, hay que saber elegir qué batallas dar y esta, en este sitio, la considero perdida.

Answer (score 0):

Muy de acuerdo con @Rubén, Creo que habría que usar solo un buen criterio. Hay muchos chicos que entran al sitio para que les resuelvan las tareas que les dan en clase y no se esfuerzan nada. [Faltaría un tipo de reporte de "Quiere que le hagan la tarea"]. Según mi punto de vista estas preguntas empobrecen el sitio y las respuestas a esas preguntas lo empobrecen aún más ya que fomentan esta mala actitud. Pero por ahí, hay casos de muy malas preguntas pero que si hubieran sido bien redactadas, pueden ser muy interesantes y pueden favorecer al sitio que exista una buena respuesta. Como indica @jachguate en su comentario:

> Si no se deben responder malas preguntas, ¿por qué existe la medalla
>   reversión?

Yo usaría un criterio tipo:

- Mala pregunta + nada interesante = Penalizar la respuesta
- Mala pregunta + interesante = Mejorar la pregunta y No penalizar respuesta

El criterio también debería ir de la mano si es la primera mala pregunta o es un usuario que no entendió de qué se trata el sitio y se le ha hecho una costumbre hacer malas preguntas y sin esfuerzo.

Comment: En los casos de los chicos que vienen a que les resuelvan las tareas, mal por ellos y quienes deben preocuparse más son los docentes ("disclaimer": soy docente aunque no del área de programación) y los que pagan las colegiaturas ya sea sus padres, quienes los becan, sus empleadores y en el caso de las instituciones públicas todos los que pagan impuestos. Como lo mencioné en mi respuesta sólo se deben penalizar las respuestas malas incluyendo las que no hay forma de saber si la respuesta responde la pregunta porque la pregunta no es clara.

Comment: Me considero una persona filosóficamente abierta a las críticas... pero te juro que no logro comprender tu argumento de las becas, instituciones públicas, empleadores e impuestos. No digo que te estés explicando mal , digo que no lo comprendo [Es un problema mío no tuyo]. Me imagino que como profesor tienes un argumento muy sólido para explicar la pertinencia de tu comentario en relación a la pregunta inicial del debate y mi comentario, pero no lo logro ver. (Ojo: no es ironía, de verdad no lo entendí)

Comment: La idea central de mi comentario es que si el AP es un estudiante flojo eso no es motivo para penalizar las respuestas a su pregunta, de hecho, las respuestas no deben juzgarse nunca con base en las cualidades del AP.

Comment: Vale, ya capté. Gracias.

Answer (score -11):

El *esfuerzo* es relativo, y por lo tanto su valoración subjetiva; no necesariamente proporcional a la calidad.
Valorar por esfuerzo es razonable cuando quien evalúa carece de experiencia y/o conocimientos.
El *esfuerzo* es un valor social que no debería estar por encima de:

- Valores *humanos* (ética, paz, bondad, solidaridad, amor, libertad, etc.)

ni

- Valores *morales* (honestidad, respeto, prudencia, compasión, humildad, etc.)

Dicho lo anterior, si bien concuerdo en desaprobar el copy/paste por falta de *ética* y *honestidad*, 
no deberíamos desestimar la *bondad*, *solidaridad*, *compasión* y/o *humildad* de quienes responden.