# Auditoría negativa con pregunta en el área gris (a mi criterio)

Tags: soporte, auditorías-de-revisión-discutibles

El día de hoy, revisando la lista de primeras publicaciones, recibí una auditoría negativa por [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/266249/21) (ahora eliminada, por lo que dejo una imagen para quien no pueda verla directamente). No es la primera, ni me asusta tanto el tema, pero realmente me parece discutible su uso en auditorías.

[image: Imagen de la pregunta]

Si bien es cierto que la pregunta no es de altisima calidad, también es cierto que cae dentro de mi criterio de [problemas simples, preguntas triviales de principantes de la programación o algún lenguaje](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4125/21) que estoy seguro luego pueden ayudar a muchos que lleguen al mismo tema por la búsqueda de google, por lo que me hubiese encantado responderla. Respondí que no había nada que hacer con ella.

Pensándolo mejor, debí intentar editarla, para agregarle la etiqueta `html`, pero es algo que seguramente hubiese hecho después, ya respondiendola.

Creo que la pregunta está en el área gris y sugiero que no sea tomada en cuenta en adelante para otras auditorías.

Comment: Me he encontrado con alguna auditoría también con la que discrepo pero no le he dado mayor importancia ¿Se puede definir que tipo de preguntas entran y si es así quien puede hacerlo, moderadores, staff?

Comment: Por otra parte no entiendo el voto negativo

Comment: @blonfu no entiendo a que te refieres con "definir que tipo de preguntas entran" . Por otro lado, yo considero el voto negativo como en desacuerdo con la opinión expresada en la publicación.

Comment: En cuanto al caso expuesto, estoy completamente de acuerdo con el cierre de dicha pregunta. La causa encaja además perfectamente con la publicación: _Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta..._

Comment: @Pikoh, el OP dice *"sugiero que no sea tomada en cuenta en adelante para otras auditorías."* y me preguntaba si eso se puede hacer

Comment: @blonfu no que yo sepa..pero trataré de informarme

Comment: @blonfu no existe una definición concreta en sí, pero en el centro de ayuda se indican los criterios que debería seguir (o no seguir) una pregunta: [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](/help/dont-ask). No sé si es eso a lo que te refieres.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no, no es eso. Hablo de las auditorías, el OP dice que no se tenga en cuenta una pregunta concreta en las auditorías y me parecía raro que se pudiera  decidir que preguntas aparecen y cuales no

Comment: @blonfu Eso tiene más sentido. Necesito mejorar mi comprensión lectora... o beber más café. A estas horas de la mañana ya ni sé :P

Comment: Beber más café es la solución a casi todo: http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mb4r20va6b1qjh397.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi voto fue el que acabó cerrando la pregunta, que acabó eliminada por la inactividad del usuario.

**Las preguntas básicas o triviales no son un problema y son bienvenidas en el sitio. Pero las preguntas que son pobres en detalles y de baja calidad, no**. Ésta es de muy baja calidad y, como ponen otros usuarios en los comentarios, no se ajusta al formato del sitio siguiendo el criterio de [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) (podría caer dentro de los puntos 1 o 3 en la lista al final de la página).

La he reabierto, pero por otros motivos diferentes a los que comentas. Volviendo a revisar la publicación, hay algo que se me pasó: la respuesta es por el propio autor de la pregunta y debería haber sido puesta como edición y no como respuesta. Incluyendo esa información en la propia pregunta, la publicación queda completa.

---

Sobre lo de quitar publicaciones de las colas de revisión y auditorías, creo que no se puede hacer (o al menos no del todo). Quizás se podría cambiar el criterio que sigue el sistema para reportar automáticamente algunas publicaciones, pero ésta en concreto fue reportada como de baja calidad por los usuarios y no por el sistema automático. En ese caso, la mejor manera de que desaparezca de las auditorías sería auditarla.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo tanto con la opinión sobre el estado original de la pregunta, como con que tras su edición incorporando lo que el OP había puesto como respuesta, la pregunta para mi es completamente aceptable. Una vez hecho esto, esta pregunta estoy seguro de que dejará de aparecer en los audits en el estado que @jachguate comentaba.